# Для чего нужна функция boundingRect()

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Какую задачу выполняет `boundingRect()`?

В документации описано, что надо переопределить 2 функции:
`void paint(*painter, const *option, QWidget *)` - с ней более менее понятно.
и
`boundingRect()`,

возвращающую прямоугольную область, на что эта область будет влиять?
Что будет, если возвратить область (0,0,0,0)?

Comment: Если я правильно понял из документации, графическая сцена будет использовать то, что вернет эта функция для определения - нужно перерисовывать Ваш графический объект или нет

Comment: @Юрий Козлов плохо понятно. дал я область (10, 10, 30 , 30 ). а дальше как графическая сцена определяет надо ли перерисовывать или нет ? :)

Comment: Я не специалист по GUI, подробного ответа дать не смогу. Если правильно  понимаю, схема должна быть примерно такая. При изменении того, что выводится на экран (курсор подвинули, окно закрыли и т.п.) сцена опрашивает все добавленные на нее объекты, и проверяет попадают ли изменения в область, которую они занимают. Если да - перерисовывает нужный объект. (Надеюсь, найдутся более опытные товарищи, которые меня поправят, и расскажут точнее и подробнее)

Comment: boundingRect должен вернуть такой прямоугольник, что все пиксели, которые вы собираетесь затронуть в paint, попали внутрь этого прямоугольника.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У QGraphicsItem есть несколько родственных функций, которые возвращают "форму" объекта, но которые не экувивалентну друг другу.

`QGraphicsItem::boundingRect` - область "занимаемая" элементом, с точки зрения рисования на экране. Должна включать в себя элементы все точки, которые будут затронуты во время перерисовки. Если вы вернете область больше чем реально необходимо - функция pain будет вызваться чаще чем нужно. Если меньше чем необходимо - то когда пользователь будет перемещать другие элементы сцены, задевая края элемента с ошибкой, то будет "затирать"  края. При перемещении собственно элемента - могут остаться "следы": сцена перерисует только область где перемещенный элемент был (определяя ее по старому положению элемента, и boundingRect) и вызовет для нового положения paint. Если paint рисовал что-то за пределами boundingRect, то эти элементы могут оказаться не стерты.

Как правило, программист знает что он собирается рисовать в paint и какого оно будет размера.

Если размер элемента меняется с какими-то параметрами, то перед изменением этих параметров важно вызвать [prepareGeometryChange](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#prepareGeometryChange) он запомнит какую область нужно перерисовать, по "старому" значению boundingRect.

`QGraphicsItem::boundingRegion` - нужно переопределить если ваш элемент "скорее одномерный, чем двумерный". Например, соединительная линия, пересекающая экран по диагонали имеет boundingRect, равный всему экрану, т.е. ее нужно было бы перерисовать буквально на любой чих.

`QGraphicsItem::shape` - форма объекта с точки зрения взаимодействия с пользователем. Т.е. область клики в которую будут считаться кликами по элементу. Если пользователь на переопределил функцию, то возвращается boundingRect.

`QGraphicsItem::opaqueArea` - непрозрачная часть объекта, с точки зрения перерисовки.  Этот метод позволяет не перерисовать часть элементов, если они лежат "под" непрозрачной частью другого элемента. По умолчанию - элемент (полу)прозрачен, т.е. возвращается пустой QPainterPath.

Comment: ого. спасибо большое